# Regex Catastrophic backtracking with a specific pattern

Tags: regex

I'm not a regex expert but my current pattern causes my front-end to freeze.

```
/^(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?$|^(\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+)?)+$/
```

Testing with : test/getCalling/logs.json,,

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Try with `^(ftp|https?):\/\/(\w+:?\w*@)?(\S+)(:\d+)?(\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\/-])?)?$|^(?:\/?([\w.-]+))+$`

Comment: @ctwheels Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: I think you're getting special characters from the copy/paste. See it in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/qdF32k/1)

Comment: Add a comma in the end of the line or a backslash and you will get a catastrophic backtracking.

Actually I want to avoid it !

try to add http://test/getCalling/logs.json, you will see it works even with the comma in the end, but removing the http:// and leaving the comma causes catastrophic backtrack

Comment: Gotcha: [here](https://regex101.com/r/qdF32k/2)

Comment: Okay it seems working but still in Java it says invalid escape sequence.. even if I type it..

Comment: Did you try copying from the link?

Comment: yes.. Same problem once I type the : after https?)

Comment: If you provide us with more details (code sample) we can better help you

Comment: Will try to figure out the Java problem but quick check your regex with this->
http://localhost:3232/test/getCalling/logs.json, 
it says that the thing is valid even with the comma, but when you remove the http://localhost:3232/  the rest of the link becomes invalid.

Comment: in Java I had to add double backslashes \\ instead of only 1 \

Comment: Yep that would be correct. You need to escape the backslashes in Java to use it in regex.

Comment: Okay perfect thank you so much.

But still seems that if we add a protocol in the beginning, the whole URL becomes valid even with , at the end.. any fix?

Comment: It's being caught by `\S+`

Comment: So is there a way to prevent adding a comma even if a link that starts with http:// .. ?

Comment: Without knowing the actual context it's hard to say. I think you're looking for a pattern like this though: [`^(?:(ftp|https?):\/\/(\w+(?::\w+)?@)?([^\/]+)(:\d+)?)?((?:\/?[\w#!:.?+=&%@\/-]*)*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/qdF32k/3)

Comment: ok this pattern does not work at all.

So what I'm look for is that I can use these two URLS

test/calling/logs.json

and also can be http ://localhost:2211/test/calling/logs.json

with preventing from adding commas in both. The first pattern works well with the first URL, but when I try to add a comma in the second at the end, it works without any problem..

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://regex101.com/r/qdF32k/4) then?

Comment: Ok this one seems to be the best ! But only 1 last touch I'd like to add.

It is to prevent using "." or "/" in the end without adding something after.

e.g :-    json.  or json/ no     json.text or json/text  yes..